# What is the main reason for upgrading to Eclipse Juno?

Tags: upgrade, eclipse-juno

Sorry if this is a strange question. But I've been using Indigo for a long time, and after upgrading to Juno I find that the UI is less responsive, has bizarre new colors (thankfully they included a Classic theme) and not a single new feature that I can see, anyway. They changed the default redo shortcut from ctrl-y to ctrl-shift-z, even though ctrl-y is a de-facto standard for that type of shortcut. Seems like a lot of changes for change's sake.

Frankly I am somewhat underwhelmed by this release. I'm not deliberately trying to be negative here, I guess I just haven't seen the light yet :-)

Does anyone have a success story where Juno was just the thing they needed to solve some specific problem or shortcoming of Indigo?

Comment: From officiall "What's new" http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_whatsnew.html for me personally is most interesting an ability to stack together views and editors.

Comment: That ctrl+shift+z is very annoying, for 5 seconds before I change to the rational ctrl+y. Why one more key could be helpful I do not get it.

Answer (score 8):

Not really a success story here...

I downgraded to 3.7 again because the performance of 4.2 is really bad. 
I didnt't tweak anything in eclipse.ini in either version, but 3.7 runs A LOT smoother with the same (quite big) workspace.

I was looking forward to "Code Recommenders" plugin, but deinstalled it after a few hours. It was kinda annoying, perhaps you have to use it a longer time to get used to it.

Xtext 2.3 is important for me, but I can have that in Indigo too.

The new layout is ugly, but thats just my opinion. Other people seem to like it... But apart from the looks, it was really slow and laggy for me when resizing or moving views.

There were some other minor bugs, perhaps my fault, no idea, but in the end I'm happy again with 3.7 :-)

Comment: Agree fully on the performance thing. I have a Lenovo laptop with a few shortcomings on the GPU side, and Juno is barely useable. Why did you find Code Recommenders annoying by the way?

Comment: Same here. I switched back. And Dislike the "glossy" (?) theme thing as well. Maybe someone who follows the eclipse thing more closely could hint something ?

Comment: @martin you can change the appearence in Preferences -> Appearence and make it (almost) look like before.

Comment: Juno is full of performance bugs -- even on a killer machine. Benchmarks are really way bad for UI stuff, and there are several total responsiveness-killers eg XML editors, PHP, switching or opening/closing editors.  I've reverted to Indigo 3.7. Totally perfect performance again.

Comment: Unfortunately (contrary to what I expected), the performance issues - and many other issues - also seem to apply to Eclipse 3.8.

Comment: @ChrisLercher thanks for that, I was thinking about giving 3.8 a try. but then I'll go with 3.7 until 4.2.2 or 4.3 is released. my colleagues aren't satisfied with 4.2.1, so that's not an option right now

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Juno is worse than Indigo. The interface is less responsive and more annoying. For instance the files are always opened in the right window and and not in he cursor one. They have to be dragged and dropped to the location but!!!... placing them in a separate/desired window requires more effort because Juno seems to place it in the most unwanted one; also, tabs can be placed harder. More annoying things come with debugging. Sorry for the developers but is crap - many times it does not to find the file in which the breakpoints are located.
I do not recommend the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment on existing posts)

Regarding UI styling:

See [1] for a short discussion on how the style can be changed. There will bis a set of new styles available soon.

Regarding Code Recommenders:

moeTi, I'd be glad to learn what you found annoying about code recommenders. The general idea or the way it's implemented? Feedback is welcome [2].

Thanks,
Marcel

[1] http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/

[2] http//www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.recommenders

Comment: I didn't really dislike it in a way that I can point out improvements.  I'm just too used to the default recommendations and the way the list is sorted. what I didn't like mostly was that  the "in method search" function always recommended me methods somewhere within a huge class when all I wanted to complete was the variable located 2 lines above.

As I said, I didn't really use it a long time, so perhaps I'm not the perfect guy to make improvements

Comment: Not sure I understood your scenario correctly. Can you create a screenshot and post it in the Recommenders forum - or link it from here? I'm sure there are a plenty of improvements we can make to let it behave more like you (and probably others too) would expect it to work (e.g., no resorting just highlighting). I just need to understand it :)