# Small Eclipse x64 distribution for Windows?

Tags: eclipse, performance, 64-bit, distribution, eclipse-juno

All the official Eclipse distributions I can find are for specific purposes: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

I currently have an installation of **Eclipse Juno** up and running with PHP, PyDev, PDT, Chrome Theme, Django Template Editor and JGit+EGit.

**This is getting a little too beefy though, the IDE runs sluggishly and drains my battery.**

So my plan is to separate these into different installations—note that separate workspaces alone wouldn't fix aforementioned issue.

Should I just use Eclipse for Testers or is there an even smaller x64 distribution I can work with? - E.g.: an unofficial one

Comment: I don't think the code that is just there (and not used) will drain you battery much. Other than that, I doubt Eclipse will ever be smallest or fastest IDE...

Comment: Yeah, it obviously will never be the smallest or fastest IDE on the market. That doesn't mean that I shouldn't try and make it lighter...

Answer (score 0):

First, Eclipse Juno 4.2 is [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_IDE#Releases) for having [performance issues](http://mmilinkov.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/juno-performance/). The situation is [improving](http://blog.springsource.org/2013/03/12/performance-improvements-in-sts-3-2-0/) rapidly, but for some cases Eclipse Juno 3.8 is used. (For example, [SpringSource](http://www.springsource.org/) distributes Spring IDE ( as [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts) distro) built on [both platforms](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts), and [as of March 2013 recommends 3.8 version](http://www.springsource.org/node/4247))

For optimization see also [Very slow Eclipse 4.2, how to make it more responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446825/very-slow-eclipse-4-2-how-to-make-it-more-responsive)

For alternative Eclipse distribution, look at [yoxos](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/) by [EclipseSource](http://eclipsesource.com/en/products/yoxos/)