# What's the difference between Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse 3.8 — what's the difference from 3.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997190/eclipse-3-8-whats-the-difference-from-3-7)

I think Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 both are Juno versions, but what are the basic difference in both?
Why two versions of Eclipse Juno together?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997190/eclipse-3-8-whats-the-difference-from-3-7

Comment: Would be good if we close this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 4.x is using the e4 platform which has, for example, lots of UI changes. Eclipse 3.8 is mostly the same but using the version 3 of the platform.